# Display R date as YYYYMMDD

Tags: r

I have a very simple request: I just want to display as.Date in YYYYMMDD format.

`as.Date("20221130", format="%Y%m%d")`

The code above displays `2022-11-30` rather than the desired `20221130`, is there a way to fix this? Preferably with base packages.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I can use `str_replace_all(as.Date("20221130", format="%Y%m%d"), "-", "")`

Comment: The question is whether you want to store the date as a Date object, and do calculations with it, or simply display the date in a particular way. If the latter then the string "20221130" already does what you want and there's no need to convert. This is explained fully in the answer from @dirk-eddelbuettel.

Comment: I do not understand why you would have a string convert to date then back to string....

Answer (score 5):

The `as.Date()` function *creates* a date object which is then *displayed* according the to standard format, which follows ISO 8601.  So try

```
> d <- as.Date("20221130", format="%Y%m%d")
> d
[1] "2022-11-30"
> class(d)
[1] "Date"
> format(d, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "20221130"
> format(d + 7, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "20221207"
>
```

As the last step shows, Date objects allow computation (and comparison and ...) and that is where the power lies.  But *internal representation* is not always *default display format*.